# What is the method of solving $2^x = 2\sqrt2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Kindly assist me in solving for $x$ in $$2^x = 2\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
2^x & = 2 \sqrt2 \\
& = 2^1 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
& = 2^{1+\frac{1}{2}} \\
& = 2^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
\implies x & = \frac{3}{2} \\
\end{align}

We can do this because if the base is the same, then by index laws we can equate the index.

Hence $x=\frac32$.

Comment: This helped me get to my answer. Excellent way of explaining it.

Answer (score 3):

Write:
$$2^x=2^{\frac{3}{2}}$$ and you'll get it.

Comment: Nice answer, but given the understanding of the OP, maybe you should add that $2^{x}$ is injective?

Comment: I think it's obvious. No?

Comment: Your answer made sense to me after I re-wrote the square-root as an exponent. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

$$2^x = 2 \sqrt2 $$
$$2^x  = 2 \times 2^ {\frac 1 2} $$
$$2^x  =2^ {1+\frac 1 2} $$
$$2^x  =2^ {\frac 3 2} $$
$$2^x \times 2^ {-\frac 3 2}=1 $$
$$2^ {x-\frac 3 2}=1 $$
$$2^ {x-\frac 3 2}=2^0 $$
$$ {x-\frac 3 2}=0 $$
$$ {x=\frac 3 2} $$

Comment: Another beautiful way of arriving at the solution. Nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

Taking log of base 2 both sides we get 
$$\log_{2} 2^x= \log_2 2\sqrt 2$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\log_2 2+ \log_2 \sqrt 2$$
$$\Rightarrow x=1+\frac {1}{2}=\frac {3}{2}$$

Comment: This is an excellent way of tackling it using log. Another very useful answer. However, can you please explain how you ended up adding the two logs after the equals sign?

Comment: You are welcome.  On this site you'll notice several methods can be given to solve a single problem. So enjoy Math.SE :-)

Comment: I understand now, for multiplying logs we must add! Thank you again!!

Comment: Yep just a property of logarithms. $$\log_x ab= \log_x a+ \log_x b$$ provided that $ab\gt 0, x\gt 0$ and $\neq 1$ and also $a, b\gt 0$